# How can I know the IP address to any website by bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, command

What is the way to know the IP address of a website such as Www.google.com  by bash script?

Comment: Is this homework? If not, why those two commands? Also, stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service, you're expected to do the actual programming yourself.

Comment: The [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
ping -c1 www.google.com | grep PING | cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1
```